# Reference a function within a library

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script for Google Docs that adds a menu item called "Utilities" -> "Insert Date" that (obviously) inserts the current date at the cursor position. I want to reuse this script for other documents and eventually offer it to others in my organisation, so I imported it as a Library in another document. However, when I try to run it, one function within the library references another, so I get an error that the .insertAtCursor function doesn't exist.

Do I need to make have everything in the library within the same function? If not, is there a way to use the call so it assumes it is within the library? I suspect this is my misunderstanding of scopes in Google Apps Script, but am not sure.

Here is the library:

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Utilities')
      .addItem('Insert Date (dd MMMM yyyy)', 'insertAtCursor')
      .addToUi();
}




/**
 * Inserts the sentence "Hey there!" at the current cursor location in boldface.
 */
function insertAtCursor() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
    // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
    // Date format defined at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
    // Make sure if you change the date format you update the menu items in the onOpen() fuction above
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd MMMM yyyy"); // "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(false);
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

And here is how I use it in the other document:

```
function onOpen() {
  InsertDate.onOpen()
}
```

If I call InsertDate.insertAtCursor from the other document that works, but doesn't make sense because I only want to call that function from the menu item. I'm not sure how I can modify this library to "just work" in another doc.

Comment: Funny how writing out the problem stirs idea... If I create a function in the other document script, it works. 

`function insertAtCursor() {  InsertDate.insertAtCursor }`

However, this still seems like more work than I would like to do (or have others do). Suggestions on a better way to do this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In the script that uses the library you'll need to create a menu and also create a function that just calls the library, as the insertAtCursor function is called in the context of the doc using the library:

```
function onOpen() {

  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Utilities')
      .addItem('Insert Date (dd MMMM yyyy)', 'insertAtCursor')
      .addToUi();
}

function insertAtCursor() {
  InsertAtCursor.insertAtCursor()
}
```

The following is a bit cleaner and would work it just isn't as obvious what's going on:

```
function onOpen() {
  InsertAtCursor.onOpen()
}

function insertAtCursor() {
  InsertAtCursor.insertAtCursor()
}
```